# Does the iterators make any side effect to its object state?

Tags: java, iterator

Technically speaking that whenever we change the pointer of an object (mean index position) does it affect object state? then how can it be  safely achieved?

---

updated:

```
//Java:
public static Collection reverse(Collection collection) {
    LinkedList newCollection = new LinkedList();
    Iterator i = collection.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
      newCollection.addFirst(i.next());
    }
    return newCollection;
  }
```

Consider the piece of code, when calling the function `addFirst(i.next())` does the state of object `i` getting changed internally?

Comment: You need to elaborate your question a little more.

Comment: It seems that "the pointer of an object" means the iterator object, and "object state" refers to the iterable. No, it doesn't. Changing iterable affects the iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It affects the state of the *iterator* (otherwise it could never change which value it returned) but it shouldn't usually affect the state of the collection it's iterating over. (There are some cases where the data can only be iterated over once, of course - imagine a stream of values coming from a server.)

Imagine a physical ist of items, and several people iterating over it. Each person might keep their finger pointing to where they'd got to in the list. As they iterate, their finger will move (mutating state) but the list itself won't change.

EDIT: As noted in comments, iterators *may* support the `remove()` operation which will affect the underlying collection if it's supported.

Comment: Iterators may support `remove()`. (It's part of the interface, but the iterator can refuse to do it; whether or not it will work should be documented in the API that produces the iterator…)